# Inequality $\frac{8}{3^x-2}\geq 3^x$.

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, substitution

Give the sum of the integers that solve the inequality $$\frac{8}{3^x-2}\geq 3^x.$$

Since $f(x)=3^x>0, \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},$ we can start by doing the substitution $t=3^x$ and get the inequality $$\frac{8}{t-2}-t\geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow f(t) = -\frac{(t+2)(t-4)}{t-2}\geq 0.$$

Looking at the signs of the f(t) we can generate the following table:

$$\begin{array}{|l|cr}
t & & -2 &  & 2 & & 4 &\\
\hline
-(t+2)(t-4) & + & 0 & + & 0 & + & 0 & - & \\
t-2 & - & - &-& 0 & - & + & + & \\ 
f(t) & - & 0 & - &\varnothing &  - & 0 & - &
\end{array}$$

So it seems that $f(t)\geq 0$ only at $t_1=-2$ and $t_2=4$. Going back to $x$, we have to discard $t_1$. The only solution seems to be $3^x = 4 \Leftrightarrow x = 2\ln{2}/\ln{3}.$

Seriously, I have no idea what is going on here. Am I being unreasonable for doing that substitution? The answer to this problem is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $3^x=t$.

Hence, $t>0$ and we need to solve
$$\frac{8}{t-2}\geq t$$ or
$$\frac{(t+2)(4-t)}{t-2}\geq0$$ or
$$2<t\leq4$$ or
$$2<3^x\leq4$$ or
$$\ln_32<x\leq2\log_32,$$
which gives $x=1$.

Comment: How do you get to $2<t\leq 4$ ?

Comment: @Parseval It's the intervals method. Draw the $t$-axes and put there $2$ and $4$ and put signs on $(4,+\infty)$, $(2,4)$ and $(-\infty,2)$.

Comment: That's what I did in my table. The LHS is always less than orequal to zero. Where is the error?

Comment: @Parseval On $(4,+\infty)$ the sign is $-$. On $(2,4)$ the sign is $+$, which we wish, and on $(-\infty,2)$ the sign is $-$.

Comment: Apparently my original post only mathematically proved that I'm a retard. Ofcourse... thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(3^x-2)^2>0$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{8(3^x-2)^2}{3^x-2}&\ge 3^x(3^x-2)^2\\
8(3^x-2)&\ge  3^x(3^x-2)^2\\
(3^x-2)[3^x(3^x-2)-8]&\le 0\\
(3^x-2)[(3^x)^2-2(3^x)-8]&\le 0\\
(3^x-2)(3^x-4)(3^x+2)&\le 0\\
(3^x-2)(3^x-4)&\le 0 \qquad\qquad (\text{Note that }3^x+2>0)\\
2\le 3^x&\le 4\\
x&=1
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice one! Thanks!